# increase the font size of String in mutable image codename one

Tags: codenameone

In form component I created an image by `Image.createImage(width, height, fillcolor)` and drawn a Sting on the image by `img.getGraphics().drawString("Part 1", 120, 80);`. I want to increase the font of string "Part 1".It looks very small on the image. Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Font class to create the largest font using `Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE)`. Alternatively you can place a true type font in the source root and load it using `Font.createTrueTypeFont()` or by getting it from a `Component`'s UIID.

Comment: I tried first option but it didn't worked. What I did is .... Font font = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE); img.getGraphics().setFont(font);

Comment: It probably worked but the size isn't much bigger than the medium size. If you want really large text you need to use a TTF file and derive a larger size in pixels.